# Cannot Print Out of For Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    N = int(input())
    list1 = []

    for data in range(N+1):
        commands, index, number = input().split()
            
        if commands == 'insert':
            list1.insert(int(index),int(number))
               
    print(list1)
```

In this code whenever I try printing the `list1` out of the `for loop` it doesn't print, neither does it give me any errors. It just displays EOF on the [HackerRank website](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-lists/problem) and in VS code it doesn't really give any output after I provide the Input

Does anyone know why?

Thanks for your time :)

[image: HackerRank output][image: VSS code Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating the loop one extra time by using `range(N+1)` so the process is waiting for one more input and it times out after some time.

Change the code to as below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    N = int(input())
    list1 = []

    for data in range(N):
        commands, index, number = input().split()
            
        if commands == 'insert':
            list1.insert(int(index),int(number))
               
    print(list1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the input is 3, then `N+1` is 4.

`range(N+1)` would then be `range(4)`.  Which is `0, 1, 2, 3` - 4 items.

i.e. The loop runs 4 times. But there is only 3 lines of input on stdin.

That's what the error is telling you. It was expecting some input but it got `EOF` - End of File.

You should just use `range(N)` or `range(1, N+1)` - which will cause the loop to run 3 times.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    N = int(input())
    list1 = []

    for _ in range(N):
        commands, index, number = input().split()
            
        if commands == 'insert':
            list1.insert(int(index),int(number))
               
    print(list1)
```